# JavaScript cookie that expires after one day

Tags: javascript, cookies

I'm attempting to learn to set a JS cookie that expires after one day, but our client is reporting intermittent results with this. Am I missing something? Is there a better way to go about doing this?

Honestly, I'd also be open to setting a session cookie to alleviate the problem, but I figured I'd see if someone spotted an error in the way we're doing this here first.

Thank you!

```js
(function($){
    
     checkCookie();
    
     function setCookie(cname, cvalue, exdays) {
      var d = new Date();
      d.setTime(d.getTime() + (exdays * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
      var expires = "expires=" + d.toUTCString();
      document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";" + expires + ";path=/";
     }
    
     function getCookie(cname) {
      var name = cname + "=";
      var ca = document.cookie.split(';');
      for (var i = 0; i < ca.length; i++) {
       var c = ca[i];
       while (c.charAt(0) == ' ') {
        c = c.substring(1);
       }
       if (c.indexOf(name) == 0) {
        return c.substring(name.length, c.length);
       }
      }
      return "";
     }
    
     function checkCookie() {
      var noShowWelcome = getCookie("sameSessionSKF");
      if (!noShowWelcome) {
       $('#home-alert').modal({
        fadeDuration: 500
         });
         setCookie('sameSessionSKF', true, 1); // sets to expire after 1 day
      }
     }
    })(jQuery);
```

```html
<script src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/jquery/3.3.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Comment: Duplicate of  [Setting cookie to expire after one day](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/32998471/setting-cookie-to-expire-after-one-day)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Instead of `expires` you can specify `Max-Age`, which is the number of seconds until the cookie expires.

```
const maxAge = 86400
document.cookie = cname + "=" + cvalue + ";Max-Age=" + maxAge + ";path=/";
```

Comment: That's an interesting solution that actually works well here. Thanks, Jishnu!